# why does this css3 animation look great in chrome and IE, but terrible in firefox?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, animation

I saw this in user [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king)'s profile, and at a cursory glance the code does appear nearly identical for all browsers. So why is this Css3 animation rendered very smoothly in chrome and IE, but choppy as heck in FF? Here is a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/GEnUU/) below find the JS+CSS

**HTML**

```
<div class='flag'>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var h = $('.flag').width();
for(var i = 0; i < h; i++){
    var flagElement = $("<div class='flag-element'>");
    flagElement.css('background-position', -i + "px 0");
    flagElement.css('-webkit-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
    flagElement.css('-moz-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
    flagElement.css('-ms-animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
    flagElement.css('animation-delay', i * 10 + 'ms');
    $('.flag').append(flagElement);
}
```

**CSS**

```
.flag {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
}
.flag-element {
    -webkit-animation:oscill 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation:oscill 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
    -ms-animation:oscill 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
    animation:oscill 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate; 
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/8VSL8Ve.gif');
    background-size: 300px 100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:1px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:0 1px grey, 0 -1px gray;
}
@-webkit-keyframes oscill {
    0% {
        top: 5%;
    }        
    100% {
        top: -5%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes oscill {
    0% {
        top: 5%;
    }        
    100% {
        top: -5%;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes oscill {
    0% {
        top: 5%;
    }        
    100% {
        top: -5%;
    }
}
@keyframes oscill {
    0% {
        top: 5%;
    }        
    100% {
        top: -5%;
    }
}
```